# Change file name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

For my project I'm setting up a page where you can change your profile and upload an image. I've got all of that to work but now I want to make my image unique by matching the file name with the Username (which already is unique)
but I couldn't find a good guide anywhere on google.
Here is my code:

```
{ 
    if (PfFoto != null)
    {
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PfFoto.FileName);

        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/PFfotos"), pic);

        PfFoto.SaveAs(path);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }                               
}
```

My username is stored in `changePF.Name`
and the file name is stored in `pic`

so does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to combine the file name with the username? Why not just assign it a unique random ID?

Comment: Becouse I need to display this image as a pf pic and its easy if the file name is the same as the user name used to login

Comment: You think it's easy. But it's actually a bad idea.What if the username were to change? You should base this off the user's ID, which should be a totally made up value not based on any attribute of the user that might change.

Comment: Okay yea I might overlooked that ill test and see what happens and then Change it to use the ID if necessary I allready got a static id from the db I use

Comment: If you need multiple photos per user, then each file should have a separate ID that's stored in a database table that has a foreign key back to the UserId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your file name to be same as your user name (*without the extension part matching*), You may use the `Path.GetExtension` method to get the file extension(ex : `.jpg` or `.png`) and concatenate that with your unique username.

```
if (PfFoto != null)
{
    var newFileName = changePF.Name + Path.GetExtension(PfFoto.FileName);
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/PFfotos"), newFileName);
    PfFoto.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `FileName` before `SaveAs` like :

```
if (PfFoto != null)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/PFfotos"), changePF.Name);

    PfFoto.SaveAs(path);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```